# replace text with regular expression keeping structure match on sublime text

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext

i been trying a few options, but i can't figure out.

this is the text i'm looking for:

```
php[whatever_is_in_between]myfunction
```

and i want to change it to this

```
=[whatever_is_in_between]myfunction
```

where [whatever_is_in_between] = \n or \n\t or \n\t\t or \nbarspace or \nbarespace\t and so on

so i found this regexp match the search text:

```
php[\n]*[\t]*[ ]*myfunction\(
```

this is the "replace with" text:

```
=[\n]*[\t]*[ ]*myfunction\(
```

but the regexp does not work on the replacement, it replace it as text.

can anybody help me with this?

thanks

Comment: Why not replace `^php` with `=`?

Comment: I don't know sublime syntax, but for me you should probably “catch” the [whatever-inbetween] with parenthesis, and add the caught string into your second expression. It could be something like `php([\n]*[\t]*[ ]*)input\(` for the pattern you search, and maybe something like `=\1input\(` for replacing expression, where `\1` would contain the expression caught between parenthesis (but one again I don't know sublime syntax, so maybe it's not `\1`)

Comment: having separate character classes for \n, \t, and spaces doesn't work. You listed "\nbarespace\t" as an example, but [\n]*[\t]*[ ]* won't match that. Try something like [\n\t ]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not using a capturing group ( ). Among other things, a capturing group allows you to take input from the the read text and then inject it into your replacement text.

I'd use a search pattern like this:

```
php\[([^\]]*)\]([\w\W]*)
```

It looks complicated, but I've set up a sample on [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/kT4kX4) that you can check out. The replacement text should look something like this:

```
[\1]\2
```

Please note that how you insert a capturing group will depend on what programming language you're using. The above should work for php.

I hope that helps,

--Jonathan

Comment: your search term didn't work for me, but the capturing group, works.  i search with this: php([\n]*[\t]*[ ]*)myfunction, and replace with this: \=\1myfunction.  thanks!